# Are Android CRUD apps supposed to be this repetitive?

Tags: java, android, crud, dry

I am getting into Android development and I feel like I am violating the DRY principle all over the place due to the nature of my app (a CRUD app, create, retrieve, update, delete).

Every time I want a list of something? I have to implement the RecyclerView adapter, the listeners/callbacks, the corresponding functions that get called in the activity, the XML for the view itself, the XML for the row items, and then the several database-level queries for each of the four CRUD operations. And that's just for one model! If I want a separate list that has to do with a different model, I implement all that stuff over again.

Is this normal? Or am I falling into some common design trap?

Comment: Tell me how does CRUD look in other frameworks? It surely does not implement itself magically. Each model has its own.

Comment: Well I do think that each model must implement all 4 CRUD operations for itself

Comment: I mean I keep reaching the same conclusion, myself... it just feels so repetitive, though. Usually when I feel this way it's because I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand the feeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was getting a little long for a comment...

Using an ORM can eliminate a lot of the boilerplate for the database stuff and let you just focus on the model.

As for lists, there may be parts you can generalize and reuse, it just depends on the specifics of your app.  If every list is completely different, you probably don't have much choice.  If they all look similar and especially if the items displayed can all implement a common interface, you can reuse most of the code and just pass in the data.